# Loop through DataTable multiple times

Tags: c#, loops, datatable

In C# (.NET 3.5) I've filled a DataTable with rows from my database. In this DataTable there are about 100 to 200 DataRows. I have to loop through this DataTable to check if the data is correct and I use 27 check-methods. First I've tried to pass the DataTable to each method and loop it. In my second attempt I've looped the DataTable once and passed the DataRow to each method. Afterwards I've benchmarked these two methods and the first method was faster than the second?

Looping the DataTable 27 times took 13 seconds.

Looping the DataTable 1 time took 18 seconds.

So what's the explanation for this? And what is really the fastest way to loop through a DataTable to check it's data?

Note: the benchmark was started right before I started the check-methods to exclude connection speed to the database.

First method:

```
private void check()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    checkStamnr();
    checkVoornaam();
    checkGebDatum();
    ...

    sw.Stop();
    sw.Reset();
}

private void checkStamnr()
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtIdentificatieRecords.Rows)
    {
        if (dr["STAMNRVOL"] == null || dr["STAMNRVOL"].GetType() == typeof(DBNull) || dr["STAMNRVOL"].equals(""))
        {
            DatabankFout df = new DatabankFout("Stamnummer is leeg.");
            listDBFouten.Add(df);
        }
    }
}
```

Second method

```
private void check()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dtIdentificatieRecords.Rows)
    {
        checkStamnr(dr);
        checkVoornaam(dr);
        checkGebDatum(dr);
        ...
    }

    sw.Stop();
    sw.Reset();
}

private void checkStamnr(DataRow dr)
{
    if (dr["STAMNRVOL"] == null || dr["STAMNRVOL"].GetType() == typeof(DBNull) || dr["STAMNRVOL"].equals(""))
    {
        DatabankFout df = new DatabankFout("Stamnummer is leeg.");
        listDBFouten.Add(df);
    }
}
```

Class DatabankFout on request:

```
public class DatabankFout
{
    public DatabankFout(string reden, bool rood)
    {
        this.reden = reden;
        this.rood = rood;
    }
    public DatabankFout(string reden) : this(reden, false)
    {
    }

    public string reden { get; set; }
    public bool rood { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hard to help without seing any code...

Comment: How heavy is your `DatabankFout` class and what is `listDBFouten`? To check which method is faster you should remove all unrelated that is identical in both. Looping 100 rows definitely cannot last 13/18 seconds(unless you're on a C64), maybe you've used a StopWatch and forgot to stop/reset during debugging(13 millis is more realistic). Instead of passing the wohole datatable or datarow, you should only pass what's needed - the data stored in the datacolumn.

Comment: Could you pleas post code on how you perform the timing.

Comment: `DatabankFout` only has some properties and listDBFouten is a `List<DatabankFout>` so it's not that heavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that a run-time difference of 25% in one run with so few items is not significant.
Run your test at least 10 times for 10000 items in the list.
If the first is still faster, I will have something to think about.

The main part of the time probably comes from creating the DatabankFout, which might be a database connection.

Comment: DatabankFout only has properties and doesn't have any connection to a database.

Comment: So how can that take so long? We are talking about a few thousand property comparisons. That can be done in much less than 1 second. Does listDBFouten.Add something like sorting or other slow things?

Comment: You can see DatabankFout in my opening post. I just tried looping the DataTable 1000 times without any check-method and it finished in 7ms. Then I tried it with one check-method and it still haven't finished after one minute.

Comment: What does listDBFouten.Add do?

Comment: As I've said before `listDBFouten` is a `List<DatabankFout>` so the Add-method will add an instance of `DatabankFout` to the list..

Comment: Ok. I've found the problem. In some check-methods I was using a method from a class that I didn't wrote. Now it appears that the method gets a value from the database so it created a new connection every time the method was called. So now I've called that method once and stored the value in a variable. The check-methods are now finished in 17ms. Thanks for mentioning it could be a database-connection. Otherwise I wouldn't have found it this fast.

Answer (score 1):

It seems impossible to me. I runned a test on my machine. Your first multiple loops method runs much slower than the one loop one.

[image]

Please check the console demo I attached.

```
class Program
{
    DataTable dtIdentificatieRecords = GetTable();

    String checkTimeSpan, check2TimeSpan;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program Test = new Program();
        Test.check();
        Test.check2();

        Console.WriteLine("checkTimeSpan: {0}", Test.checkTimeSpan);

        Console.WriteLine("check2TimeSpan: {0}", Test.check2TimeSpan);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This example method generates a DataTable.
    /// </summary>
    static DataTable GetTable()
    {
        //
        // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
        //
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("STAMNRVOL", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        //
        // Here we add five DataRows.
        //
        for (int a = 0; a < 999999; a++)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(a%2==0?a.ToString():"", "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        }
        return table;
    }

    private void check()
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Start();

        checkStamnr();
        checkStamnr();
        checkStamnr();
        checkStamnr();
        checkStamnr();

        stopwatch.Stop();

        checkTimeSpan = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString();

        stopwatch.Reset();
    }

    private void checkStamnr()
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtIdentificatieRecords.Rows)
        {
            if (dr["STAMNRVOL"] == null || dr["STAMNRVOL"].GetType() == typeof(DBNull) || dr["STAMNRVOL"].Equals(""))
            {
                DatabankFout df = new DatabankFout("Stamnummer is leeg.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void check2()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        foreach (DataRow dr2 in dtIdentificatieRecords.Rows)
        {
            checkStamnr2(dr2);
            checkStamnr2(dr2);
            checkStamnr2(dr2);
            checkStamnr2(dr2);
            checkStamnr2(dr2);

        }

        sw.Stop();

        check2TimeSpan = sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString();

        sw.Reset();
    }

    private void checkStamnr2(DataRow dr)
    {
        if (dr["STAMNRVOL"] == null || dr["STAMNRVOL"].GetType() == typeof(DBNull) || dr["STAMNRVOL"].Equals(""))
        {
            DatabankFout df = new DatabankFout("Stamnummer is leeg.");

        }
    }

}

public class DatabankFout
{
    public DatabankFout(string reden, bool rood)
    {
        this.reden = reden;
        this.rood = rood;
    }
    public DatabankFout(string reden)
        : this(reden, false)
    {
    }

    public string reden { get; set; }
    public bool rood { get; set; }
}
```